# Realtime fulldome video splitting

Tags: video, streaming, effects

I need to split fulldome video stream to several projectors for planetarium. I wrote hlsl (and glsl) shader which does exactly what I need and has some configurable parameters. It works in MPC:HC that comes with K-Lite codec pack. But MPC doesn't have API for plugins as I know so I can't make an interface for configuring the shader or splitting the video for several video outputs. So I'm looking for software that can help me with this. 
I need two things: 
1) Apply configurable effect to video (cut and unwrap a sector for chosen projector)
2) Show results in separate windows or transmit directly to projectors.